# What is this QUnit Library code about?

Tags: javascript, prototype, qunit

```
(function() {
    function F() {}
    F.prototype = QUnit;
    QUnit = new F();
    // Make F QUnit's constructor so that we can add to the prototype later
    QUnit.constructor = F;
}());
```

I do not understand :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In short this changes the QUnit global reference to a new object that uses prototypal inheritance to extend the original QUnit object. This way you can extend/change QUnit without breaking the original object. Check this for more details: http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html